# JSON array from php

Tags: javascript, json, validation, alerts

```
[
    {
        "id":"26",
        "latitude":"10.308749502342007",
        "longitude":"123.88429984649656"
    },
    {
        "id":"28",
        "latitude":"10.313816172726275",
        "longitude":"123.89030799468992"
    }
]
```

I have this json array from `php` and I want to alert the id which is 26. How can I do that.I am using `$.ajax`. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert JSON string to javascript Object

```
var json_string = '[{"id":"26","latitude":"10.308749502342007","longitude":"123.88429984649656"},{"id":"28","latitude":"10.313816172726275","longitude":"123.89030799468992"}]';
var result = JSON.parse(json_string);
alert(result[0].id); //Will alert 26
```

Comment: @user3157712 Glad it worked! If it successfully work for you, then select this as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to access element by id:

```
function parseData(data) {
    var result = {};
    $(data).each(function(i, el) {
        result[el.id] = el;
    });
    return result;
}

// ...

data  = parseData(response); // response from $.ajax
alert(data['26'].latitude); // access element by id
```